# Firefox button borders are brighter

Tags: border

I have put custom borders on my buttons. I clearly state a colour and it works on all browsers except for Firefox...once again Firefox is the odd one out. I am telling the border to be #252525 but it is way brighter, and when inspecting element the border colour is correct. What is causing it to be brighter?
If I change it to "red" it becomes a very bright shade of red.

(Bottom is Chrome, top is Firefox, IE + Edge are the same as Chrome)
https://gyazo.com/c32a819548a253c5502356877e7bc128

```css
input.button {      
 height: 50px;
 width: calc(400px / 3);
 border: 0px;
 float: left;
 background-color: #191919;
 color: #AEAEAE;
 font-family: standard;
 font-size: 40px;
 cursor: pointer;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #252525;
 border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="x1.5">
```

Comment: This is a new one on me. Please post all relevant code

Comment: @mayersdesign Is that alright?